# jQuery Optimisation Multiple Selectors

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

At the top of my script I two variables holding two selectors:

```
    var all_open = $('ul#festival_dates li.controls a:eq(0)');
    var all_close = $('ul#festival_dates li.controls a:eq(1)');
```

I'm getting there with Jquery, I'm now at the point where I'm looking at my code and finding ways to write much more efficient scripts. One thing I noticed using YUI Compressor is that it said "[WARNING] Try to use a single 'var' statement per scope." and highlighted the two lines above, has anyone got any suggestions about this, or can explain a more technical description of what this means?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your replie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What it' saying is this:

```
var all_open = $('ul#festival_dates li.controls a:eq(0)'),
    all_close = $('ul#festival_dates li.controls a:eq(1)');
```

to use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator).

As for performance, http://jsperf.com/single-var, I'm not sure it makes much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of repeating the word `var` you can use commas to delimit additional variable declarations:

```
var all_open = $('ul#festival_dates li.controls a:eq(0)'),
all_close = $('ul#festival_dates li.controls a:eq(1)');
```